# Is it grammatical to have duplicate 'it'?: __ it it __

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, repetition

Is it grammatically correct to use the word *it* twice in a row? When doing so, do you have to separate the two using a comma?

If there are different situations please use examples.

My examples:

- When I find it it can be filed away.
- Because of the size of it it doesn't fit in the array.

I am asking because I am a habitual double it'er and a colleague called me out on it.

Comment: Can you give an example?  I think I get your meaning, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It would help if OP posted an example that motivated the question; otherwise it seems like vague musing.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. As for your specific examples, I do not think they are wrong, but the first would be better with a comma, and the second would be better as a genitive (and with a comma)—"Because of its size, it doesn't fit in the array"

Comment: thanks @nohat - do you think it is confusing to read?

Comment: What would this be down voted?  It seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 4):

There are certain idiomatic phrases ending in *it* which could conceivably be followed by another it:

- So **I take it** it is not going well.
- **Why is it** it always rains when I forget my umbrella?

Both of these above examples could have an optional *that* between the two *it*s—but it is not required and these sentences are grammatical (to me, at least).

I searched for "[it it](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=28959530)" in The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA) and most of the results were scan errors, typos, or not real matches. There were some cases where an *it*-final clause was followed by an *it*-initial clause where the comma is optional. For example:

- You have to find the gap in the wall, and if you don't know it it's not easy.
- What he means is, don't call attention to yourself because once you get it it's hard to shake.
- This time someone holds the chair firm, and when I hit it it doesn't move.
- ... when he read the Declaration of Independence, because in it it says, 'All men are created equal'

I think most editors would agree the above examples would be improved by introducing the optional comma between the two *it*s, but the rules for commas are flexible. In many cases, such as in these examples, they are optional and their inclusion is really up to the writer.

[This brief blog entry](https://suite101.com/a/the-optional-comma-three-instances-of-writers-discretion-a336316) discusses several cases where commas are optional.